# Django: Reverse for 'booking' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

Sorry if this looks like a duplicate question, but I've looked through the others and the issue doesn't seem to be the same.

Exception:

```
Reverse for 'booking' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The error is thrown up with the following on the courses.html template:

```
{% url 'booking' %}
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^courses/(?P<course_code>\w+)/$', views.course, name="course"),
url(r'^booking/(?P<course_code>\w+)/$', views.booking, name="booking"),
```

views:

```
def booking(request, course_code):
current_course = Course.objects.filter(short_title=course_code)
template = loader.get_template('website/booking.html')
context = Context({
    'current_course': current_course,
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def courses(request):
latest_course_list = Course.objects.order_by('-start_date')
template = loader.get_template('website/courses.html')
context = Context({
    'latest_course_list': latest_course_list,
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The other questions on here seem to be issues with putting quotes around the variable in the template, but this doesn't look like the same issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `booking` url takes one parameter as `course_code`, hence you are getting error.

You should update the line `{% url 'booking' %}` appropriately to pass some `course_code` to the url.

So you need to update it with something like `{% url 'booking' course_code %}`, here I assume to have `course_code` parameter available in template, you can change it according to your code.

Comment: Great - that's the one. I was trying to split up the url by doing {% url 'booking' %}{{ course.short_title }}, so instead I used {% url 'courses' course.short_title %} and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per your url

```
url(r'^booking/(?P<course_code>\w+)/$', views.booking, name="booking"),
```

you need to pass a parameter for `course_code` in your template like this

```
{% url 'booking' course_code_value %}
```